# picturebox opening too late

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show "Loading.., please wait" gif by getting content from web.
I have tried the following code, but Picturebox opening too late.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;

    webSatList = new WebSatelliteList(this, XMLSatList, name);

    webSatList.LoadTPList();
    TPListToBeAdded = webSatList.GetTPListToBeAdded();
    TPListToBeRemoved = webSatList.GetTPListToBeRemoved();

    drawTPListGridView(TPListToBeAdded, TPListToBeRemoved);
}

public void drawTPListGridView(List<TPInfo> TPListToBeAdded, List<TPInfo> TPListToBeRemoved)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;        
    //draw TP List ..
}
```

Picturebox is openning after this line:

> "TPListToBeRemoved = webSatList.GetTPListToBeRemoved();"

I have tried to fix this problem by using backgroundworker (the following code) and the same problem has been seen. Also, I have used the popup form instead of PictureBox nothing has changed.

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    webSatList = new WebSatelliteList(this, XMLSatList, name);

    webSatList.LoadTPList();
    TPListToBeAdded = webSatList.GetTPListToBeAdded();
    TPListToBeRemoved = webSatList.GetTPListToBeRemoved();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    drawTPListGridView(TPListToBeAdded, TPListToBeRemoved);
}

public void drawTPListGridView(List<TPInfo> TPListToBeAdded, List<TPInfo> TPListToBeRemoved)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;        
    //draw TP List ..
}
```

How can i fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Backgroundworker attempt is added.

Comment: I have added Thread.Sleep(1000) and the problem still continues. It takes about 7 seconds and it is not quick.

Comment: Too much unknown code.  Add pictureBox1.Update() to force it to paint immediately after you made it visible.

Comment: You may simply want to try an  Application.DoEvents(); after making the PB visible so that the GUI gets time to refresh.

Comment: Thanks TaW it is OK now. How does Application.DoEvents(); fix this problem?

Comment: I have loaded .gif image to picturebox, but gif is starting to move too late. PB is visible but gif doesn't move for 5 seconds. This is my new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not *entirely* sure what you're trying to do here, but chances are you want to implement the `async` / `await` pattern.

Mark your button press as `async`

`private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

For anything that you need to wait for should then be `await`ed and it will keep your form redrawing so it doesn't freeze up. For example, something like:

`await Task.Run(() => loadPictureBox());`

Or you could make your loadpicturebox method asynchronous by giving it a signature of `async Task`.

The problem you're likely having is that the form will not update or refresh itself until the click method has exited. This means if you first make it display a loading image, and then load the next image in the *same method* that the form will freeze up until both operations have finished and the method has exited.

The `async` `await` pattern means that while it's doing some processing or whatever, let windows carry on drawing the form and handling actions on it.